# Shell parameter expansion on arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, parameter-expansion

Say I read some data into a Bash array:

```
$ IFS=" " read -a arr <<< "hello/how are/you iam/fine/yeah"
```

Now, I want to print the first `/`-sliced field for each element in the array.

What I do is to loop over the elements and use shell parameter expansion to strip everything from the first `/`:

```
$ for w in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "${w%%/*}"; done
hello
are
iam
```

However, since `printf` allows us to print the whole content of the array in a single expression:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
hello/how
are/you
iam/fine
```

... I wonder if there is a way to use the shell parameter expansion `${w%%/*}` at the time of using `printf`, instead of looping over all the elements and doing it against every single one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, I just found the way: just use the parameter expansion normally, only that against `${arr[@]}` instead of `${arr}`!

```
$ IFS=" " read -a arr <<< "hello/how are/you iam/fine/yeah"
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]%%/*}"
hello
are
iam
```

Greg's wiki helped here:

> [Parameter Expansion on Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)
>
> BASH arrays are remarkably flexible, because they are well integrated
>   with the other shell expansions. Any parameter expansion that can be
>   carried out on a scalar or individual array element can equally apply
>   to an entire array or the set of positional parameters such that all
>   members are expanded at once, possibly with an additional operation
>   mapped across each element.
>
> ```
> $ a=(alpha beta gamma)  # assign to our base array via compound assignment
> $ echo "${a[@]#a}"      # chop 'a' from the beginning of every member
> lpha beta gamma
> $ echo "${a[@]%a}"      # from the end
> alph bet gamm
> $ echo "${a[@]//a/f}"   # substitution
> flphf betf gfmmf
> ```

Comment: This is actually quite cool, can't believe I didn't about trying that myself.

Comment: @andlrc I was also very suprised! It its quite simple and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @fedorqui's answer, if OP wants to output an array instead of a string, this worked for me-

```
a=(alpha beta gamma)
newArr=( "${a[@]//a/f}" )
```

P.S. I personally arrived to this post looking to output an array after doing substitutions on each element of an array.