# Using the `paste` and being aware of input filenames

Tags: bash, paste

Let's say I have files: `foo.tsv` and `bar.tsv`, whose contents are shown below:

```
foo.tsv
1
2
3
4
5

bar.tsv
a
b
c
d
e
```

If I run `paste foo.tsv bar.tsv > foo_bar.tsv` I get:

```
foo_bar.tsv
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    e
```

Though this is very nice, I'd like to automatically name `foo_bar.tsv` to eliminate the possibility of ending up with a misleading file, e.g., in case of typos.

Let's say:

`paste foo.tsv baz.tsv > foo_bar.tsv # foo_bar should have been foo_baz here.`

In the simple case of 2 inputs is hard to get something wrong, but if I do:

`paste foo.tsv baz.tsv bar.tsv baz.tsv > foo_baz_bar_baz.tsv`

things are likely to get messy.

Is there a way of automatically naming the output file? How can I make the redirection operator aware of its inputs?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array to keep track of the files you want to `paste` together:

```
files=("foo.tsv" "bar.tsv")
```

Then, `paste "${files[@]}"` will expand to `paste "foo.tsv" "bar.tsv"`.

Finally, to redirect to a file whose name is based on the arguments, you can use something like

```
$ IFS=_
$ echo "${files[*]%.*}"
foo_bar
```

That is, remove everything from the last dot to all the elements in the array and then print them together setting the internal field separator to `_`.

Doing the same thing over all the elements in the array is described in [Shell parameter expansion on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37698203/1983854) and printing them together using `${var[*]}` is described in [Bash Reference Manual → Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) (kudos to [anishane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793796/anishsane) for the suggestion in comments).

Then, it is a matter of redirecting the `paste` command to a file created with this `printf`:

```
command > "$(echo "${files[*]%.*}".tsv)"
```

All together:

```
files=("foo.tsv" "bar.tsv")
paste "${files[@]}" > "$(IFS=_; echo "${files[*]%.*}".tsv)"
```

Comment: Good use of BASH array ++

Comment: One way to take care of trailing underscore: `files=("foo.tsv" "bar.tsv"); IFS=_; echo "${files[*]%.*}"`

Comment: @anishsane oooh nice! Many thanks, I always forget about `${array[*]}`

Comment: You can probably put `IFS=_` inside `$(...)` as `$(IFS=_;echo "${files[*]%.*}".tsv)`, so as to keep the parent shell environment clean...

Answer (score 3):

You could also set up a function that does most of the work for you

```
pastefile(){

    for i in "$@";do
       newfile+="${i%.*}_"
    done
    ext="${1##*.}"

    paste "$@" > "${newfile%_}.${ext}"

}
```

Run as

```
$ pastefile foo.tsv bar.tsv
$ cat foo_bar.tsv

1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
```

Will also work with filenames with spaces.