# removing last character of every word in files

Tags: regex, bash, text, awk, replace

I have multiple files with just one line of simple text. I want to remove last character of every word in each file. Every file has different length of text.

The closest I got is to edit one file:

```
awk '{ print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1); print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1); }' file.txt
```

But I can not figure out, how to make this general, for files with different words count.

Comment: to be sure, *1 line of simple text* and *every word* mean there is 1 line per file with 0 to several word inside and each word have to be modified (seeing lot of reply removing only the last char of the line)

Comment: Yes, there are actually 1 to several words inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk` to loop till max fields in each row upto `NF`, and apply the `substr` function.

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf "%s ", substr($i, 1, length($i)-1)}}END{printf "\n"}' file
```

For a sample input `file`

```
ABCD ABC BC
```

The `awk` logic produces an output

```
ABC AB B
```

Another way by changing the record-separator to `NULL` and just using `print`:-

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="";}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print substr($i, 1, length($i)-1); print " "}}END{print "\n"}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)sub(/.$/,"",$x)}7' file
```

this should do the removal.

If it was tested ok, and you want to overwrite your file, you can do:

```
awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)sub(/.$/,"",$x)}7' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Example:

```
kent$  awk '{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)sub(/.$/,"",$x)}7' <<<"foo bar foobar"   
fo ba fooba
```

Comment: funny to use `7` for printing a line, a special meaning for 7 instead of frequent 1 for this purpose ?

Comment: yes, the special meaning is lucky number! :-D  just kidding.. 7 is easier for me to reach. I think right index finger is more convenient than left little finger. You know, a heavy vim user cares about keystrokes

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a Bash approach:

Since [`${var%?}` removes the last character of a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259042/40596):

```
$ var="hello"
$ echo "${var%?}"
hell
```

And [you can use the same approach on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37698108/1983854):

```
$ arr=("hello" "how" "are" "you")
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]%?}"
hell
ho
ar
yo
```

What about going through the files, read their only line (you said the files just consist in one line) into an array and use the abovementioned tool to remove the last character of each word:

```
for file in dir/*; do
   read -r -a myline < "$file"
   printf "%s " "${myline[@]%?}"
done
```

Comment: My only concern was the size constraint of the files when using pure `bash` logic like this. Is it really slow when processing huge files compared to `awk`?

Comment: @Inian we should test it. However, parsing a number of one-line files does not seem to be a very CPU intensive task, so bothering about performance is more of an academic debate.

Comment: That being said, it is also recommendable to keep this answer in mind: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765/40596).

Comment: Thanks! Asked the question in first place because of that particular topic in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Sed version, assuming word are only composed of letter (if not, just adapt the class `[[:alpha:]]` to reflect your need) and separate by space and puctuation

```
sed 's/$/ /;s/[[:alpha:]]\([[:blank:][:punct:]]\)/\1/g;s/ $//' YourFile
```

awk (gawk for regex boundaries in fact)

```
 gawk '{gsub(/.\>/, "");print}' YourFile

 #or optimized by @kent ;-) thks for the tips
 gawk '4+gsub(/.\>/, "")' YourFile
```

Comment: if golf a bit on the gawk line, you can do `gawk '7+gsub(...)' file`

Comment: did'nt know the `7+gsub` as "pattern matcher", nice tip

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat foo
word1
word2 word3
$ sed 's/\([^ ]*\)[^ ]\( \|$\)/\1\2/g' foo
word
word word
```

A *word* is any string of characters excluding space (=`[^ ]`).

**EDIT:** If you want to enforce POSIX (`--posix`), you can use:

```
$ sed --posix 's/\([^ ]*\)[^ ]\([ ]\{,1\}\)/\1\2/g' foo
word
word word
```

This `\( \|$\)` changes to `\([ ]\{,1\}\)`, ie there is an optional space in the end.

Comment: with GNU sed, posix failed with the `\|` (reason of the add/remove of space in my sed)

Comment: Didn't notice posix being required.

Comment: not a critic, just  telling a limitation even if more and more it is used on linux where this limitation is not the case. Here, half of my systems are still aix (or sun) without gawk ou gnu sed and i have to composed with.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Fixed (hopefully :).